# GitLab: SMTP mail works from console only

Tags: smtp, gitlab

I have a Linux Ubuntu 16.04.1 installed on a VM. I have installed GitLab 8.12.6 using the instructions from the GitLab site, and encountered problems in making Gitlab to send mails.

I want to use an SMTP server with another domain name than the GitLab server.
The configuration was made accordingly to [the examples provided by GitLab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md).

I followed the [official debugging tips from GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/troubleshooting/debug.html#mail-not-working).

As expected, `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method` returns `=> :smtp`; and **I was able to send mail using the `Notify.test_email` method**.
Nevertheless, new users still don't receive any confirmation email.

Under Admin Area > Monitoring > Background Jobs, nothing special is displayed. The dashboard is neat (no failed/busy/... job).
The logs don't show any issue with emails.
I even see:

> Sent mail to xxx@yyy.com (897.3ms)

The health check reports that everything is healty.

The only surprising element is that the running sidekiq process is git and shows only question marks under PID/CPU/MEM/STAT/...

I am surprised that I can send mails from the GitLab console and still fails when sending on its own.

Which further steps do you recommend to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

I ran through the GitLabs logs (docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html) and did not find anything.

I wanted to understand if the mail server is causing the issue. (I can't access its logs.) So I configured GitLab to use my GMail mail as smtp server. My GMail has 2FA enabled, thus I created a token. GMail lets you display when a token has been used for the last time.

After re-configuring the GitLab server, I requested a new confirmation email (server_name.com/users/confirmation/new) and didn't receive anything. The interesting part is that the token still had never been used.

Afterwards, I checked the GMail configuration using the admin console: the token was used and I received the mail.

From this I deduce that **GitLab is not even trying to access the SMTP server**.

Comment: Check the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign-up confirmation email was disabled. I enabled it under the settings in the admin area: "Send confirmation email on sign-up".

The confusing part is:

I was checking the email setup using the "Request new confirmation" form. This form will send a mail only to users that were created while the aforementioned setting was enabled. No email will be sent to other users created with confirmation email turned off, even if they make an explicit request using the form.

This is because their email address has already been marked as verified. Their requests are simply ignored without mention in the log files.